# $\lim_{x \to 0+}\log_{10}{\tan^2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x \to 0+}\log_{10}{\tan^2x}$

What is the value of this one?

Could you please give me some hints on this problem?

Comment: Hmmm $n$ is missing in your limit....

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Sorry.. I fixed it

Comment: @Sharky Kesa fixed his answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \log_{10}(\tan^2(x))$. Since $f(x) = f(x+\pi)$ and $f$ isn't constant, $f$ is a periodic function, so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist.

---

FIXED QUESTION:

Observe that $x \to 0^+$, $\tan^2(x) \to 0^+$, so $\log(\tan^2(x)) \to -\infty$.

Comment: sorry.. there was a mistake.. it is as $x$ goes to 0+